# PENTAHO SPOON - Split a single table input into multiple excel output

Tags: etl, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

Hi I have a huge dataset with multiple fields and I want to split this dataset into different excel outputs using Pentaho Spoon.

My dataset looks like this:

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3 COLUMN4
 a          1       2       3
 a          2       3       4
 a          3       4       5
 b          1       2       3
 b          2       3       4
 c          1       2       3
 c          2       3       4
```

And I want to group by each distinct variable in column 1 and then export each of these subdatasets into multiple excel files, so I have 3 different outputs that look like this:

```
EXCEL FILE 1 : a  1  2  3
               a  2  3  4
               a  3  4  5
EXCEL FILE 2 : b  1  2  3
               b  2  3  4
EXCEL FILE 3:  c  1  2  3
               b  2  3  4
```

So far this is what I've done. However, I don't know what to do afterwards in what I believe should be done in a second transformation. Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the output file has the same layout for all the different options (as displayed in your example), you can just use a single "Text file output" step with different file names (eable option "Accept file name from previous field" and select the field with the filename from combo "File name field"). For example, use the value in "COLUMN1" as the output filename (have a previous step to concat that value with the output directory as well). That way the step will create one output file for each value in "COLUMN1".

On the other hand, if the output layout differs between each value in COLUMN1, then the option would be to use a "Switch / Case" step and have one "Text file output" step for each different output layout.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create one job that contain two tranformations. First transformation is your above transformation.
2. second tranformation should start with 2 steps - one read from your row result, another one read from input (IMP_TOTAL_INPUT), then join their data. later filter the COLUMN1 = row result. and lastly use Microsoft Excel output with filename "include time in filename?" so will create excel file with different filename.
3. For tranformation 2 in the job, in tranformation setting/properties, click "Execute every input row" (checkbox) to loop through all your row result (Column1 value).